# Anchor Link HTML

Tags: html, hyperlink, anchor

I'm trying to set up an anchor link for my site to jump to a particular heading on the same page. Below is my current code, but when you select the link nothing happens. Any help would be great, thanks!

```
Section I want the link to jump to

<div class="heading1">
<h2 style="margin-bottom:-5px;font-size:40px;"><a id="#work"></a>content</h2>
<p style="font-size: 26px;">content</p>
</div>

Link

<div class="contact mobile">
<a href=“#work”>Work</a>
</div>
```

Comment: `#` doesn't belong in the `ID` attribute, and you don't need to have a separate `<a>` element, just add the ID to the `<h2>` node. Please try to do more searching before asking because there are a lot of duplicates to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

need to refer the href to the id of the div you want to jump to `href="#jump"`

```html
<div class="heading1" id="jump">
<h2 style="margin-bottom:-5px;font-size:40px;">content</h2>
<p style="font-size: 26px;">content</p>
</div>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

<div class="contact mobile">
<a href="#jump">Work</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

brother remove hash from attribute id="#work" use just id="work">